# Inequality for $\sin(20°)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, functional-inequalities

Prove that $$\frac{1}{3} < \sin{20°} < \frac{7}{20}$$

Attempt 
$$\sin60°=3\sin20°-4\sin^{3}(20°)$$
Taking $\sin20°$=x

I got the the equation as
$$8x^3-6x+\sqrt{3} =0$$ 
But from here I am not able to do anything. Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Edit-graph of p(x)
[image]

Comment: Hint:  if $p(x)$ is your cubic, what is $p\left( \frac 13\right)$?  What is $p\left( \frac 7{20}\right)$?  That, plus a quick sketch of the graph should do it.

Comment: @lulu In that region p(x) is decreasing so p(1/3)>p(x)>p(7/20) and hence $\frac{1}{3} <x<\frac{7}{20}$

Comment: Well, I think this is what you are trying to prove, no?  I don't see what argument you are making other than to restate the question.

Comment: Sketch the graph!  What can you say about the roots of $p(x)$?  Can you roughly describe their locations?

Comment: Yes this is what I was trying to prove. I wanted affirmation from your side only to be only sure about my steps. But, thanks for help.

Comment: You could prove it with Taylor's Inequality. I don't know if you want to go to that much trouble. https://sites.math.washington.edu/~aloveles/ArchivedMaterials/Math126/TaylorNotesReview1.pdf

Comment: @lulu roots approx(-1),(0.34),&(0.64)

Comment: Well, how do you know that?  If you are using a numerical root finder, then you hardly need the crude estimate called for in the question.  Crude techniques should suffice to tell you that one root is negative, one root is between $0$ and $.5$ and the third is greater than $.5$   Can you tell which of those three regions contains the single root you care about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(x)$ denote the cubic.

Since $$\lim_{x\to - \infty}p(x)=-\infty<0\quad \quad p(0)>0\quad \quad  p(.5)<0\quad \quad\lim_{x\to + \infty}p(x)=+\infty$$ we see that one root is negative, a second lies between $0$ and $.5$ and the third is greater than $.5$

Of course $\sin(20^{\circ})$ is positive and, since $0<20<30$ we see that $\sin(20^{\circ})<.5$  Thus the root we want is the middle one of the three.  We then remark that $$p\left( \frac 13 \right)>0 \quad \& \quad p\left( \frac 7{20}\right)<0$$  so the root we care about must be between $\frac 13$ and $\frac {7}{20}$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly for fun, here's a way to show that

$$6\left(1\over3\right)-8\left(1\over3\right)^3\lt\sqrt3\lt6\left(7\over20\right)-8\left(7\over20\right)^3$$

with only a small amount of multi-digit arithmetic:

$$6\left(1\over3\right)-8\left(1\over3\right)^3=2-{8\over27}\lt2-{8\over28}=2-{2\over7}={12\over7}$$

and $12^2=144\lt147=3\cdot7^2$, which gives the first inequality, while

$$6\left(7\over20\right)-8\left(7\over20\right)^3={7\over10}\left(3-\left(7\over10\right)^2 \right)={7\over10}\left(300-49\over100 \right)\gt{7\over10}\cdot{250\over100}={7\over4}$$

and $7^2=49\gt48=3\cdot4^2$ gives the second inequality.

Comment: Thanks for another way to attempt such inequalities.